# How to graph relationships between movies and actors (that they performed in common) in Neo4J movies database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a custom CSV with movies data with the following strucuture:

```
id,title,media_type,original_language,actor
1002185.0,A Million Miles Away,movie,en,Emma Fassler
447332.0,A Quiet Place,movie,en,Noah Jupe
```

and i want to graph in neo4j the actors (names) that share one or more movies (title) between each other, the code where i load the data:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///movies_neo_graph/part-00000-c5c5507e-5501-4adb-87fc-38be1d908076-c000.csv" AS row
CREATE (m:Movie)
SET m = row,
m.id = toInteger(row.id),
m.title = toString(row.title),
m.language = toString(row.original_language);

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///movies_neo_graph/part-00000-c5c5507e-5501-4adb-87fc-38be1d908076-c000.csv" AS row
CREATE (a:Actor)
SET a = row,
a.name = toString(row.actor),
a.movie_id = toInteger(row.id);
```

Then I setup the relationship between nodes Movie and Actor:

```
MATCH (a:Actor),(m:Movie)
WHERE a.movie_id = m.id
CREATE (a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m);
```

This is my first time in Neo4J and i don't know how to perform the query, i tried with

```
MATCH (a:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie) 
RETURN a.name AS actor, COLLECT(DISTINCT m.title) AS movies_acted, COUNT(m.title) AS movies_cnt
ORDER BY movies_cnt DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

And the result is a table but not a graph:

[image: Neo4J query table]

Any ideas? really appreciate the help

Comment: Are you clear on the difference between a graph ( i.e. an image of a plot or chart ) and a mathematical graph ( i.e. a model of connections using vertices and edges ).  This question " the result is a table but not a graph" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Since your query did not return any nodes, relationships, or paths, no *graph visualization* is possible.

For example, if you want the Neo4j Browser to display the `a` nodes in a graph visualization, your `RETURN` clause will also have to include `a` as a term (not just `a.name`, which is only a string property and not the entire node).